# How to solve property undefined with a while loop?

Tags: javascript

The script below will replace all the image tags for real image objects. Unfortunately, I receive an `Uncaught TypeError` error. This is because Javascript counts from zero to 3 in my example, instead of 1 to 4. The length of the array is 4.

How can I avoid this error (so I also get the console log after the `while` loop)?

```
var raw_content = {
        "text"  : "Test image 1 [image] Test image 2 [image] Test image 3 [image] Test image 4 [image]",
        "media" :[
                    {
                        "src":          "http://placehold.it/400x200",
                        "caption":      "This is a caption"
                    },{
                        "src":          "images/gallery/sh0.png",
                        "caption":      "This is a caption"
                    },{
                        "src":          "http://placehold.it/400x200",
                        "caption":      "This is a caption"
                    },{
                        "src":          "images/gallery/sh0.png",
                        "caption":      "This is a caption"
                    }
                ]
    };

    // find img one by one
    var image_counter = 0;
    var text_buffer = raw_content.text;

    var replaceTag = function () {
        text_buffer = text_buffer.replace("[image]", raw_content.media[image_counter].src);
        console.log(text_buffer);
        console.log(image_counter);
        console.dir(raw_content.media[image_counter]);
        image_counter++;
    };

    while ( text_buffer.search('[image]') !== null ) {
        replaceTag();
    }

    console.log('String buiten while loop = %s', text_buffer);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with 1-4 vs. 0-3, it has to do with what [`String#search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) does.

`String#search` interprets what you give it as *a regular expression*. So `[image]` means "any of these characters: `i`, `m`, `a`, `g`, or `e`" because `[...]` is a *character class* in a regular expression. (Later, your `String#replace` works correctly, because if you give `String#replace` a string, it uses it literally.) So since the string has those characters even after four replacements, you try to run a fifth time, and that's when you run into trouble. Also, separately, `String#search` returns the index where the string was found, which will be a number (-1 if not found), which will *always* be `!== null`.

If you just change your loop to:

```
while ( text_buffer.indexOf('[image]') !== -1 ) {
    replaceTag();
}
```

...you won't go beyond the end of your array (as long as the text and the array do match up, e.g., the text doesn't have more occurrences of `[match]` than the array has entries).

**Live Example:**

```js
var raw_content = {
        "text"  : "Test image 1 [image] Test image 2 [image] Test image 3 [image] Test image 4 [image]",
        "media" :[
                    {
                        "src":          "http://placehold.it/400x200",
                        "caption":      "This is a caption"
                    },{
                        "src":          "images/gallery/sh0.png",
                        "caption":      "This is a caption"
                    },{
                        "src":          "http://placehold.it/400x200",
                        "caption":      "This is a caption"
                    },{
                        "src":          "images/gallery/sh0.png",
                        "caption":      "This is a caption"
                    }
                ]
    };

    // find img one by one
    var image_counter = 0;
    var text_buffer = raw_content.text;

    var replaceTag = function () {
        text_buffer = text_buffer.replace("[image]", raw_content.media[image_counter].src);
        /*
        console.log(text_buffer);
        console.log(image_counter);
        console.dir(raw_content.media[image_counter]);
        */
        image_counter++;
    };

    while ( text_buffer.indexOf('[image]') !== -1 ) {
        replaceTag();
    }

    document.body.innerHTML =
      'String buiten while loop = ' + text_buffer;
```

Alternately, of course, escape the `[` and the `]` and compare with -1 (and probably use a literal regular expression, for clarity):

```
while ( text_buffer.search(/\[image\]/) !== -1 ) {
    replaceTag();
}
```

Although as [Oriol points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025007/how-to-solve-property-undefined-with-a-while-loop/34025167?noredirect=1#comment55807175_34025167), if you need a regex but you're just checking for whether there are any occurrences, probably better to use `test`:

```
while ( /\[image\]/.test(text_buffer) ) {
    replaceTag();
}
```

Comment: The first while loop is working, the other one with regular expression not. Would like to know the other one as well :)

Comment: @Caspert: Because we're both being silly: `String#search` returns the index where the string was found, not the string or `null`. :-) I've fixed the answer.

Comment: If the specific index doesn't matter, I think it's better to use `/\[image\]/.test(text_buffer)` instead of `search`.

Comment: @Oriol: I'd probably use `indexOf`, no need to involve a regex engine in a non-regex match. But yes, if using regex, I'd use `test`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.